# Mongodb select document using Phalcon php ODM

Tags: phalcon

I am developing an application using phalcon php and Mongo DB. I want to select `post_type = 'page'` from the following document

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("53f896db461584542200002b"),
   "post_con" : {
      "post_date" : "12-05-14",
      "post_title" : "Test",
      "post_content" : "test content",
      "post_category" : "test cat",
      "post_type" : "page",
      "post_status" : "published",
      "post_modified" : "12-05-14"
   },
   "comment_status" : "open",
   "link_code" : "test-page",
   "seo" : {
      "meta_desc" : "test desc",
      "meta_key" : "test key"
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This seems like a basic query that should be covered in the [Phalcon documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/odm.html#finding-documents). Since `post_type` is an embedded document, you need to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to reference the field name (eg. "post_con.post_type").

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got he answer

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for the same, here is the full code.

```
$post = Posts::find(array(
            'conditions'=>array('post_con.post_type'=>'blog') ));

    $this->view->postlist = $post;
```

And in view,

```
{% for posts in postlist %}

{{ posts.post_con['post_title'] }}
{{ posts.post_con['post_content'] }} 

{% endfor  %}
```

Hoe this will help for someone.